# 'All Questions' vs 'Unanswered' tabs switching button is confusing

Tags: discussion, user-interface, user-experience, filtering

For me, this **All Questions**/**Unanswered** button doesn't fit nicely in the UI.

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

https://stackoverflow.com/questions

It is graphically joined with the other buttons that actually are toggle buttons or tab headers. However, the **All Questions**/**Unanswered** button is something really different. Not only it is a toggle button that changes its title, but it also affects which tabs/toggle buttons are currently available.

[image: screenshot]

Can we/should we make it more clear, that it's not another tab like **Votes** or **No Answers**?

I really think that it is confusing why the most of same looking buttons act like tab headers while the single most right button suddenly is an entirely different story.

---

***Update***

Anyone seeing this actually? Because in the comments, @SamuelLiew mentions that he doesn't observe those buttons at all.

Comment: I don't see that on https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbAVt.png Perhaps it's an A/B testing thing?

Comment: I see this both on Meta and on SO. I will check that on another machine later.

Comment: It would be helpful if you have a link to the page where you are seeing this (if it's not what I linked above)

Comment: I checked that on my home PC - I see those buttons (either **Unanswered** or **All Questions**). The link is exactly the same as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered. The second one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: I just revisited this in a private browsing session (not logged in). Apparently there are two versions, which points to some A/B testing going on? https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUPDC.gif Anyway, I can see this issue on meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered, so another possibility is that I got the new tab nav due to being in a Team.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Stack Exchange team will introduce a completely new filtering interface soon.

[This is the post on Meta-SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781/custom-question-lists-finding-questions-you-can-answer).

That new filtering interface will look like this:

[image: screenshot]

The feature will be rolled out 2018-2019. So keeping that in mind, my question/issue report is now obsolete.